# Which SQL Server component is in charge with checking cached execution plans for a given query?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, architecture, cache, plan-cache

I understand that whenever SQL server receives a query it looks in the cache plan for any matching execution plans for that query. However, most of the resources that I encountered  don't specify which component is in charge of this lookup. [This article](https://blog.devart.com/sql-server-architecture.html) suggests that it's the Buffer Manager, but I failed to find any evidence for this in Microsoft's [Query processing architecture guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15). On the other hand, the speaker in [this presentation](https://youtu.be/34VqSliEfsc?t=2563) (around 42:43) seems to suggest that it's the Cmd Parser. So, which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Optimize SELECT statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#optimizing-select-statements)

> The input to the Query Optimizer consists of the query, the database
> schema (table and index definitions), and the database statistics. The
> output of the Query Optimizer is a query execution plan, sometimes
> referred to as a query plan or execution plan.

From the above-quoted text, Query Optimzer's job is to create the execution plan. Hence you can infer that Query Optimizer will check the plan cache for the existence of a plan for the same query hash.